# html responsive textarea / button / table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm working on a site with a textarea / button / table in the body content.

My content is responsive enough, except for very thin displays (like mobile) in which case the table does not wrap and becomes unusable, and the button doesn't expand to fill the entire area.

(in line code element doesn't seem to be playing nice, but this jsfiddle is a better example)

https://jsfiddle.net/martinradio/b4z735tk/40/

How can I make the table more responsive so that when my window gets resized, the table has some sort of word wrap (like a scroll) similar to the textarea

```css
            button {
                border: 2px solid black;
            }
            table, th, td {
                border: 2px solid black;
                background: white;
                color:black;
                  height: 100%;
                  }
                  
                  table { 
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <link rel='icon' href='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/48-bubbles/48/06.Tags-512.png' type='image/x-icon' />
    <title>tagger.site</title>

    <!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!-- Popper.JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- bootstrap css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- font-awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>

<!-- Style -->
<style>
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";


body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

/*
#sidebar ul li a:hover { background: rgb(6, 255, 193); color: rgb(247, 1, 255); } `;
*/

p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

.btn-info {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #b81717;
    border-color: #52b817;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
    /*
    padding: 15px 10px;
    margin-right: 77px;
    */
    /* background: rgb(11, 223, 212); */
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    margin-left:11px
}

.navbar-btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    /*  background: #63c23e; NAVBAR BACKGROUND */
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -250px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 20px;
    /* background: #6d7fcc; */
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
    /* padding: 20px 0; */
    /* border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b; */
}

#sidebar ul p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
        margin-left: -250px;
    }
    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    #sidebarCollapse span {
        color: pink
        display: inline;
    }
}

#imageModal{
    z-index:3;
}

/* Sidebar expand/collapse button */
#sidebarCollapse{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    
    margin-left: 84%;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 1px rgba(0 ,0, 0, .3);
    border: none;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
}

/* Bottom of sidebar image stuff */
.responsive {
    width: 90%;
    bottom:20px;
    margin-left:5%;
    margin-right:5%;
}

/* image footer color text center */
.sidebar-footer{
text-align: center;
font-size: 1.1rem;
/*font-family:'Consolas' */
}

/* image footer color boxes */
.colorBox {
  /*float: left;*/
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

</style>

<style>

/* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
#colorImageDisplay {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#colorImageDisplay:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
.modal-content, #caption {
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)}
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>

<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="wrapper" class="toggled">
    
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <nav id="sidebar" style='background: #f8f0e8; color:#000000;'>

        <!-- sidenav top title -->
        <div id='sidebarTop' class="sidebar-header" style='background: #513e2a'>
            <!-- sidebar top title text -->
            <h3 style='color: #ffffff' style='font-weight: bold; text-size:12px'><strong>asdasdr</strong></h3> 
            <!-- sidebar expand/collapse button -->
            <button id='sidebarCollapse'>
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/24/000000/menu.png"/>
            </button> 
        </div>

        <!-- sidenav list of items -->
        <ul class="list-unstyled components sideBarOption" style='background: #180d04; color: #ffffff;'>
            <!-- about page -->
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
         
        </ul>

     
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="content" style='background: #cec5ac;'>
        

        <div class="col-sm-12">

            <div class="col" >
                <div class="row" style=' overflow: auto; margin: auto; background: #917e73; color: #ffffff'>
                    <div class="col" style=''>
                        <h1 class="widgettitle"><strong>page title</strong></h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-100"></div>
                    
                    <div class="col" style=''>
                        <a id='githubUrl' target="_blank" href='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v&#x3D;0df7k__KEHw'>Github</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col" >
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="row" style=' margin: auto;'>
                   <!-- page main content -->
                  <div class="container-fluid" style='color: #000000'>

                      <div style="margin-top:-30px;">

 <!-- discogstagger output -->
        <hr>
        <h3>Comma-Separated Metadata Tags:</h3>
        <div class='outputDiscogstaggerBox' style='margin-left:15px;'>
            <div class='row'>
                <textarea class="inputbox" id="tagsBox" rows="7" cols="44" placeholder="Booker T. Jones,Priscilla Jones,Booker T & The MGs,The Mar-Keys,The Stax Staff,The Packers,The RCO All-Stars,Priscilla Coolidge,Booker T. & Priscilla,1971,France,The Wedding Song,She,The Indian Song,Sea Gull,For Priscilla,The Delta  Song,Why,Mississippi Voodoo,Cool  Black Dream,Sweet Child Youre Not Alone,Booker T. & Priscilla 1971,Booker T. Jones 1971,"></textarea>
                <button class="btn default copyButton" style="cursor: pointer;" id='copyToClipboarad' onclick="copyToClipboard('#inputBox')" type="button">Copy</button>
                <div>
                    <table class="fixed h-100" align="left" style="white-space:nowrap; table-layout: fixed; width: 533px; " height="100" id="adjustments">
                        <tbody>
                        <!-- Columns -->
                        <tr>
                            <th style="text-align:center; width: 6%;"><input type="checkbox" id='selectAll' checked></th>
                            <th style="text-align:center; width: 25%;">Tags Type</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center; width: 46%;">Tags</th>
                        </tr>

                        <!-- Artists -->
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="releaseArtistsCheckbox" id="releaseArtistsCheckbox" checked="" onchange="prepUpdateTagsBox()">
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">Release Artist(s)</td>
                            <td>
                            <div style="text-align:center;">
                                <input type="range" class="releaseArtistsSlider" id="releaseArtistsSlider" min="0" max="100" value="100" onchange="prepUpdateTagsBox()">
                                <div class='float-left' id="releaseArtistsSliderValue">100%</div>
                                <div class='float-right' id='releaseArtistsNumber'>0 chars  </div>
                            </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <!-- Release Info -->
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="releaseInfoCheckbox" id="releaseInfoCheckbox" checked="" onchange="prepUpdateTagsBox()">
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">Release Info</td>
                            <td>
                            <div style="text-align:center;">
                                <input type="range" class="releaseInfoSlider" id="releaseInfoSlider" min="0" max="100" value="100" onchange="prepUpdateTagsBox()">
                                <div class='float-left' id="releaseInfoSliderValue">100%</div>
                                <div class='float-right' id='releaseInfoNumber'>0 chars</div>
                            </div>
                            </td>

                        </tr>

                        <!-- Tracklist -->
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="tracklistCheckbox" id="tracklistCheckbox" checked="" onchange="prepUpdateTagsBox()">
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">Tracklist</td>
                            <td>
                            <div style="text-align:center;">    
                                <input type="range" class="tracklistSlider" id="tracklistSlider" min="0" max="100" value="100" onchange="prepUpdateTagsBox()">
                                <div class='float-left' id="tracklistSliderValue">100%</div>
                                <div class='float-right' id='tracklistNumber'>0 chars</div>
                            </div>
                            </td>

                        </tr>

                        <!-- Combinations -->
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="combinationsCheckbox" id="combinationsCheckbox" checked="" onchange="prepUpdateTagsBox()">
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">Combinations</td>
                            <td>
                            <div style="text-align:center;">
                                <input type="range" class="combinationsSlider" id="combinationsSlider" min="0" max="100" value="100" onchange="prepUpdateTagsBox()">
                                <div class='float-left' id="combinationsSliderValue">100%</div>
                                <div class='float-right' id='combinationsNumber'>0 chars</div>
                            </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                

                      </div>


                  </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>

        </div>

        
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    setHoverColor();
    //setColors()

    async function setHoverColor(){
        var sheet = document.createElement('style')
        //create css style rule for on-hover tab and on hover github url
        let innerHTMLHoverColorStyle = `
            /* githubUrl hover */
            #githubUrl:hover{
                color:blue;
            }

            #sidebar ul li a:hover { 
                background: #8c743c; 
                color: #ffffff;
            } `;
        sheet.innerHTML = innerHTMLHoverColorStyle 
        document.head.appendChild(sheet);
    }

    async function setColors(){
        console.log('setcolors()')
        let colors = await getColors()
        let imgPath = colors.imgPath
        //6 possible colors: 
        //Vibrant
        //LightVibrant
        //DarkVibrant
        //Muted
        //LightMuted
        //DarkMuted
        
        //get high contrast colors for text
        /*
        let sidebarColorBackground = colors.colors['DarkVibrant']
        console.log("sidebarColorBackground = ", sidebarColorBackground)
        sidebarColorBackground = sidebarColorBackground.substring(4, sidebarColorBackground.length-1);
        console.log("sidebarColorBackground = ", sidebarColorBackground)
        sidebarColorBackground = sidebarColorBackground.split(',');
        console.log("sidebarColorBackground = ", sidebarColorBackground)
        sidebarColorBackground_hex = rgbToHex(213, 23, 36)
        console.log("sidebarColorBackground_hex = ", sidebarColorBackground_hex)
        let sidebarColorBackground_text = invertColor(sidebarColorBackground_hex)
        console.log("sidebarColorBackground_text = ", sidebarColorBackground_text)
        */
        
        //change color display text and set color box hex value
        //make all colors visible 
        //document.getElementById('pageColorsText').style.display = "block";
        /*
        //color 1
        var color1 = colors.colors['Vibrant']
        var color1_hex = rgbToHex(color1)
        document.getElementById("color1Hex").innerText = `Color 1: ${color1_hex}`
        //color 2
        var color2 = colors.colors['LightVibrant']
        var color2_hex = rgbToHex(color2)
        document.getElementById("color2Hex").innerText = `Color 2: ${color2_hex}`
        //color 3
        var color3 = colors.colors['DarkVibrant']
        var color3_hex = rgbToHex(color3)
        document.getElementById("color3Hex").innerText = `Color 3: ${color3_hex}`
        //color 4
        var color4 = colors.colors['Muted']
        var color4_hex = rgbToHex(color4)
        document.getElementById("color4Hex").innerText = `Color 4: ${color4_hex}`
        //color 5
        var color5 = colors.colors['LightMuted']
        var color5_hex = rgbToHex(color5)
        document.getElementById("color5Hex").innerText = `Color 5: ${color5_hex}`
        //color 6
        var color6 = colors.colors['DarkMuted']
        var color6_hex = rgbToHex(color6)
        document.getElementById("color6Hex").innerText = `Color 6: ${color6_hex}`
        */ 

        //change display image source
        //document.getElementById('colorImageDisplay').src=`${imgPath}`

        //setup image modal popup
        //imageModalSetup()

        //change colors
        var sheet = document.createElement('style')

        let hoverColor = `#8c743c`;

        let innerHTMLHoverColorStyle = `#sidebar ul li a:hover { background: ${hoverColor}; } `;
        sheet.innerHTML = innerHTMLHoverColorStyle 
        document.head.appendChild(sheet);

        let innerHTMLStyle = `

        /* main page body background color solid
        body { background: red; } */

        /* sidebar_header_background_color 
        #sidebarTop {background: ${colors.colors['LightMuted']};}   */ 

        /* sidebar_background_color 
        #sidebar { background: linear-gradient(0deg, ${colors.colors['LightVibrant']}, ${colors.colors['Muted']}); } */

        /* active tab color 
        #currentPage { background: ${colors.colors['LightVibrant']}; } */

        /* main page body background color gradient 
        body { background: linear-gradient(2deg, color3_hex, color6_hex);} */ 

        /* ul ul a { expanded tab background color 
        .sideBarOption { background: ${colors.colors['Muted']}; }  */

        /* sidebar hover color */
        #sidebar ul li a:hover { background: ${colors.colors['DarkVibrant']}; } `;

        //console.log("innerHTMLStyle = ", innerHTMLStyle)
        //sheet.innerHTML = innerHTMLStyle 
        //document.head.appendChild(sheet);
    }

    function invertColor(hex) {
        if (hex.indexOf('#') === 0) {
            hex = hex.slice(1);
        }
        // convert 3-digit hex to 6-digits.
        if (hex.length === 3) {
            hex = hex[0] + hex[0] + hex[1] + hex[1] + hex[2] + hex[2];
        }
        if (hex.length !== 6) {
            throw new Error('Invalid HEX color.');
        }
        // invert color components
        var r = (255 - parseInt(hex.slice(0, 2), 16)).toString(16),
            g = (255 - parseInt(hex.slice(2, 4), 16)).toString(16),
            b = (255 - parseInt(hex.slice(4, 6), 16)).toString(16);
        // pad each with zeros and return
        return '#' + padZero(r) + padZero(g) + padZero(b);
    }

    function padZero(str, len) {
        len = len || 2;
        var zeros = new Array(len).join('0');
        return (zeros + str).slice(-len);
    }
    
    //rgb to hex 
    function componentToHex(c) {
        var hex = c.toString(16);
        return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
    }

    function rgbToHex(color) {
        //color = string like rgb(a,b,c)
        //remove string parts
        color = color.substring(4, color.length-1);
        //turn into arr
        color = color.split(',');
        
        return "#" + componentToHex(parseInt(color[0])) + componentToHex(parseInt(color[1])) + componentToHex(parseInt(color[2]));
    }

    //setup image modal popup
    imageModalSetup()

    async function imageModalSetup(){
      
        // Get the modal
        var modal = document.getElementById("imageModal");

        // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
        var img = document.getElementById("colorImageDisplay");
        
        //make image visible
        img.style.display = "block";
        var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
        var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
        img.onclick = function(){
            modal.style.display = "block";
            modalImg.src = this.src;
            //captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
        }
       

        // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        span.onclick = function() {
            $('#imageModal').fadeOut(500);
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        //refresh button 
        const refreshButton = document.getElementById('refreshButton');
        const refreshPage = () => {
            location.reload();
        }
        refreshButton.addEventListener('click', refreshPage)

        

        //if clicking outside modal, close modal
        $(document).click(function (e) {
            console.log('close modal')
            if ($(e.target).is('#imageModal')) {
                $('#imageModal').fadeOut(500);
            }
        });

        //on escape key click, close modal
        $(document).keydown(function(event) { 
            if (event.keyCode == 27) { 
                $('#imageModal').fadeOut(500);
            }
        });

        //side bar collapse event
        $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
            $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
        });

    });

    //make request to colors backend
    function getColors(){
        return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/getColors',
                data: {
                    type: "varValue",
                },
            }).then((data) => {
                resolve(data)
            }).catch((err) => {
                reject(err)
            });
        })
    }

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: The content inside the table is too bog to allow wrapping. Like that slider for example

Comment: It looks like you're setting the table to a fixed 533px width. In addition to Mosia's suggestion, you'll probably need to remove this fixed width, change the units to something driven by the container or viewport size, or use CSS media queries to set a different width for narrower layouts.

Comment: ive tried removing anyplace where I set a fixed width like 533px; but that leads to the issue of getting the table to be displayed as the same length under the textarea, I tried adding padding and margin -right too

Comment: Perhaps you can utilize max-width to make the widths responsive yet the same length. Media queries can also be useful if you pinpoint at what width your table breaks and adjust the width or height from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited your code here: https://jsfiddle.net/r0bny6h7/

1. To make the table itself responsive on smaller screens, I changed the fix width of 553px to "max-width: 553px". Essentially what this does is on larger screens, makes sure that the element does not go over 553px, but on smaller screens, it will automatically reduce in size to fit the screen.
2. To expand the button on smaller screens, just add a max-width (in this case, "max-width: 553px" to match the table) and "width: 100%" to ensure that it takes up the full width on smaller screens.
3. To make the table contents have word wrap, just add "word-wrap: break-word;" and "white-space: normal;" to the table, th, td.
4. Just a small note, but it was a bit difficult to navigate through your code since you mixed inline and declarative CSS styles. I would suggest sticking to one type, especially if you have styles that will be reused throughout the code (for example, you add "text-align: center" to a lot of the table contents. You can clean it up by applying it to the whole element instead, or a specific class.)

```css
            button {
                border: 2px solid black;
            }
            table, th, td {
                border: 2px solid black;
                background: white;
                color:black;
                height: 100%;
                white-space: normal;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
                  
                  table { 
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <link rel='icon' href='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/48-bubbles/48/06.Tags-512.png' type='image/x-icon' />
    <title>tagger.site</title>

    <!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!-- Popper.JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- bootstrap css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- font-awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>

<!-- Style -->
<style>
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";


body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

/*
#sidebar ul li a:hover { background: rgb(6, 255, 193); color: rgb(247, 1, 255); } `;
*/

p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

.btn-info {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #b81717;
    border-color: #52b817;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
    /*
    padding: 15px 10px;
    margin-right: 77px;
    */
    /* background: rgb(11, 223, 212); */
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    margin-left:11px
}

.navbar-btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    /*  background: #63c23e; NAVBAR BACKGROUND */
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -250px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 20px;
    /* background: #6d7fcc; */
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
    /* padding: 20px 0; */
    /* border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b; */
}

#sidebar ul p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
        margin-left: -250px;
    }
    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    #sidebarCollapse span {
        color: pink
        display: inline;
    }
}

#imageModal{
    z-index:3;
}

/* Sidebar expand/collapse button */
#sidebarCollapse{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    
    margin-left: 84%;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 1px rgba(0 ,0, 0, .3);
    border: none;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
}

/* Bottom of sidebar image stuff */
.responsive {
    width: 90%;
    bottom:20px;
    margin-left:5%;
    margin-right:5%;
}

/* image footer color text center */
.sidebar-footer{
text-align: center;
font-size: 1.1rem;
/*font-family:'Consolas' */
}

/* image footer color boxes */
.colorBox {
  /*float: left;*/
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

</style>

<style>

/* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
#colorImageDisplay {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#colorImageDisplay:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
.modal-content, #caption {
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)}
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>

<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="wrapper" class="toggled">
    
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <nav id="sidebar" style='background: #f8f0e8; color:#000000;'>

        <!-- sidenav top title -->
        <div id='sidebarTop' class="sidebar-header" style='background: #513e2a'>
            <!-- sidebar top title text -->
            <h3 style='color: #ffffff' style='font-weight: bold; text-size:12px'><strong>asdasdr</strong></h3> 
            <!-- sidebar expand/collapse button -->
            <button id='sidebarCollapse'>
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/24/000000/menu.png"/>
            </button> 
        </div>

        <!-- sidenav list of items -->
        <ul class="list-unstyled components sideBarOption" style='background: #180d04; color: #ffffff;'>
            <!-- about page -->
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
         
        </ul>

     
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="content" style='background: #cec5ac;'>
        

        <div class="col-sm-12">

            <div class="col" >
                <div class="row" style=' overflow: auto; margin: auto; background: #917e73; color: #ffffff'>
                    <div class="col" style=''>
                        <h1 class="widgettitle"><strong>page title</strong></h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-100"></div>
                    
                    <div class="col" style=''>
                        <a id='githubUrl' target="_blank" href='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v&#x3D;0df7k__KEHw'>Github</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col" >
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="row" style=' margin: auto;'>
                   <!-- page main content -->
                  <div class="container-fluid" style='color: #000000'>

                      <div style="margin-top:-30px;">

 <!-- discogstagger output -->
        <hr>
        <h3>Comma-Separated Metadata Tags:</h3>
        <div class='outputDiscogstaggerBox' style='margin-left:15px;'>
            <div class='row'>
                <textarea class="inputbox" id="tagsBox" rows="7" cols="44" placeholder="Booker T. Jones,Priscilla Jones,Booker T & The MGs,The Mar-Keys,The Stax Staff,The Packers,The RCO All-Stars,Priscilla Coolidge,Booker T. & Priscilla,1971,France,The Wedding Song,She,The Indian Song,Sea Gull,For Priscilla,The Delta  Song,Why,Mississippi Voodoo,Cool  Black Dream,Sweet Child Youre Not Alone,Booker T. & Priscilla 1971,Booker T. Jones 1971,"></textarea>
                <button class="btn default copyButton" style="cursor: pointer; max-width: 553px; width: 100%;" id='copyToClipboarad' onclick="copyToClipboard('#inputBox')" type="button">Copy</button>
                <div>
                    <table class="fixed h-100" align="left" style="white-space:nowrap; table-layout: fixed; max-width: 533px;" height="100" id="adjustments">
                        <tbody>
                        <!-- Columns -->
                        <tr>
                            <th style="text-align:center; width: 6%;"><input type="checkbox" id='selectAll' checked></th>
                            <th style="text-align:center; width: 25%;">Tags Type</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center; width: 46%;">Tags</th>
                        </tr>

                        <!-- Artists -->
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="releaseArtistsCheckbox" id="releaseArtistsCheckbox" checked="" onchange="prepUpdateTagsBox()">
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">Release Artist(s)</td>
                            <td>
                            <div style="text-align:center;">
                                <input type="range" class="releaseArtistsSlider" id="releaseArtistsSlider" min="0" max="100" value="100" onchange="prepUpdateTagsBox()">
                                <div class='float-left' id="releaseArtistsSliderValue">100%</div>
                                <div class='float-right' id='releaseArtistsNumber'>0 chars  </div>
                            </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <!-- Release Info -->
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="releaseInfoCheckbox" id="releaseInfoCheckbox" checked="" onchange="prepUpdateTagsBox()">
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">Release Info</td>
                            <td>
                            <div style="text-align:center;">
                                <input type="range" class="releaseInfoSlider" id="releaseInfoSlider" min="0" max="100" value="100" onchange="prepUpdateTagsBox()">
                                <div class='float-left' id="releaseInfoSliderValue">100%</div>
                                <div class='float-right' id='releaseInfoNumber'>0 chars</div>
                            </div>
                            </td>

                        </tr>

                        <!-- Tracklist -->
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="tracklistCheckbox" id="tracklistCheckbox" checked="" onchange="prepUpdateTagsBox()">
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">Tracklist</td>
                            <td>
                            <div style="text-align:center;">    
                                <input type="range" class="tracklistSlider" id="tracklistSlider" min="0" max="100" value="100" onchange="prepUpdateTagsBox()">
                                <div class='float-left' id="tracklistSliderValue">100%</div>
                                <div class='float-right' id='tracklistNumber'>0 chars</div>
                            </div>
                            </td>

                        </tr>

                        <!-- Combinations -->
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="combinationsCheckbox" id="combinationsCheckbox" checked="" onchange="prepUpdateTagsBox()">
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">Combinations</td>
                            <td>
                            <div style="text-align:center;">
                                <input type="range" class="combinationsSlider" id="combinationsSlider" min="0" max="100" value="100" onchange="prepUpdateTagsBox()">
                                <div class='float-left' id="combinationsSliderValue">100%</div>
                                <div class='float-right' id='combinationsNumber'>0 chars</div>
                            </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                

                      </div>


                  </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>

        </div>

        
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    setHoverColor();
    //setColors()

    async function setHoverColor(){
        var sheet = document.createElement('style')
        //create css style rule for on-hover tab and on hover github url
        let innerHTMLHoverColorStyle = `
            /* githubUrl hover */
            #githubUrl:hover{
                color:blue;
            }

            #sidebar ul li a:hover { 
                background: #8c743c; 
                color: #ffffff;
            } `;
        sheet.innerHTML = innerHTMLHoverColorStyle 
        document.head.appendChild(sheet);
    }

    async function setColors(){
        console.log('setcolors()')
        let colors = await getColors()
        let imgPath = colors.imgPath
        //6 possible colors: 
        //Vibrant
        //LightVibrant
        //DarkVibrant
        //Muted
        //LightMuted
        //DarkMuted
        
        //get high contrast colors for text
        /*
        let sidebarColorBackground = colors.colors['DarkVibrant']
        console.log("sidebarColorBackground = ", sidebarColorBackground)
        sidebarColorBackground = sidebarColorBackground.substring(4, sidebarColorBackground.length-1);
        console.log("sidebarColorBackground = ", sidebarColorBackground)
        sidebarColorBackground = sidebarColorBackground.split(',');
        console.log("sidebarColorBackground = ", sidebarColorBackground)
        sidebarColorBackground_hex = rgbToHex(213, 23, 36)
        console.log("sidebarColorBackground_hex = ", sidebarColorBackground_hex)
        let sidebarColorBackground_text = invertColor(sidebarColorBackground_hex)
        console.log("sidebarColorBackground_text = ", sidebarColorBackground_text)
        */
        
        //change color display text and set color box hex value
        //make all colors visible 
        //document.getElementById('pageColorsText').style.display = "block";
        /*
        //color 1
        var color1 = colors.colors['Vibrant']
        var color1_hex = rgbToHex(color1)
        document.getElementById("color1Hex").innerText = `Color 1: ${color1_hex}`
        //color 2
        var color2 = colors.colors['LightVibrant']
        var color2_hex = rgbToHex(color2)
        document.getElementById("color2Hex").innerText = `Color 2: ${color2_hex}`
        //color 3
        var color3 = colors.colors['DarkVibrant']
        var color3_hex = rgbToHex(color3)
        document.getElementById("color3Hex").innerText = `Color 3: ${color3_hex}`
        //color 4
        var color4 = colors.colors['Muted']
        var color4_hex = rgbToHex(color4)
        document.getElementById("color4Hex").innerText = `Color 4: ${color4_hex}`
        //color 5
        var color5 = colors.colors['LightMuted']
        var color5_hex = rgbToHex(color5)
        document.getElementById("color5Hex").innerText = `Color 5: ${color5_hex}`
        //color 6
        var color6 = colors.colors['DarkMuted']
        var color6_hex = rgbToHex(color6)
        document.getElementById("color6Hex").innerText = `Color 6: ${color6_hex}`
        */ 

        //change display image source
        //document.getElementById('colorImageDisplay').src=`${imgPath}`

        //setup image modal popup
        //imageModalSetup()

        //change colors
        var sheet = document.createElement('style')

        let hoverColor = `#8c743c`;

        let innerHTMLHoverColorStyle = `#sidebar ul li a:hover { background: ${hoverColor}; } `;
        sheet.innerHTML = innerHTMLHoverColorStyle 
        document.head.appendChild(sheet);

        let innerHTMLStyle = `

        /* main page body background color solid
        body { background: red; } */

        /* sidebar_header_background_color 
        #sidebarTop {background: ${colors.colors['LightMuted']};}   */ 

        /* sidebar_background_color 
        #sidebar { background: linear-gradient(0deg, ${colors.colors['LightVibrant']}, ${colors.colors['Muted']}); } */

        /* active tab color 
        #currentPage { background: ${colors.colors['LightVibrant']}; } */

        /* main page body background color gradient 
        body { background: linear-gradient(2deg, color3_hex, color6_hex);} */ 

        /* ul ul a { expanded tab background color 
        .sideBarOption { background: ${colors.colors['Muted']}; }  */

        /* sidebar hover color */
        #sidebar ul li a:hover { background: ${colors.colors['DarkVibrant']}; } `;

        //console.log("innerHTMLStyle = ", innerHTMLStyle)
        //sheet.innerHTML = innerHTMLStyle 
        //document.head.appendChild(sheet);
    }

    function invertColor(hex) {
        if (hex.indexOf('#') === 0) {
            hex = hex.slice(1);
        }
        // convert 3-digit hex to 6-digits.
        if (hex.length === 3) {
            hex = hex[0] + hex[0] + hex[1] + hex[1] + hex[2] + hex[2];
        }
        if (hex.length !== 6) {
            throw new Error('Invalid HEX color.');
        }
        // invert color components
        var r = (255 - parseInt(hex.slice(0, 2), 16)).toString(16),
            g = (255 - parseInt(hex.slice(2, 4), 16)).toString(16),
            b = (255 - parseInt(hex.slice(4, 6), 16)).toString(16);
        // pad each with zeros and return
        return '#' + padZero(r) + padZero(g) + padZero(b);
    }

    function padZero(str, len) {
        len = len || 2;
        var zeros = new Array(len).join('0');
        return (zeros + str).slice(-len);
    }
    
    //rgb to hex 
    function componentToHex(c) {
        var hex = c.toString(16);
        return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
    }

    function rgbToHex(color) {
        //color = string like rgb(a,b,c)
        //remove string parts
        color = color.substring(4, color.length-1);
        //turn into arr
        color = color.split(',');
        
        return "#" + componentToHex(parseInt(color[0])) + componentToHex(parseInt(color[1])) + componentToHex(parseInt(color[2]));
    }

    //setup image modal popup
    imageModalSetup()

    async function imageModalSetup(){
      
        // Get the modal
        var modal = document.getElementById("imageModal");

        // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
        var img = document.getElementById("colorImageDisplay");
        
        //make image visible
        img.style.display = "block";
        var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
        var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
        img.onclick = function(){
            modal.style.display = "block";
            modalImg.src = this.src;
            //captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
        }
       

        // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        span.onclick = function() {
            $('#imageModal').fadeOut(500);
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        //refresh button 
        const refreshButton = document.getElementById('refreshButton');
        const refreshPage = () => {
            location.reload();
        }
        refreshButton.addEventListener('click', refreshPage)

        

        //if clicking outside modal, close modal
        $(document).click(function (e) {
            console.log('close modal')
            if ($(e.target).is('#imageModal')) {
                $('#imageModal').fadeOut(500);
            }
        });

        //on escape key click, close modal
        $(document).keydown(function(event) { 
            if (event.keyCode == 27) { 
                $('#imageModal').fadeOut(500);
            }
        });

        //side bar collapse event
        $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
            $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
        });

    });

    //make request to colors backend
    function getColors(){
        return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/getColors',
                data: {
                    type: "varValue",
                },
            }).then((data) => {
                resolve(data)
            }).catch((err) => {
                reject(err)
            });
        })
    }

</script>

</html>
```